# random array doesn't return value

Tags: php

I want to return random value. i dont why it doenst work. the code like this.

my table has 3 fields: id, items, color.

the value are:

```
1-bicycle-blue
2-car-black
3-phone-blue
```

**Query**

```
$a="SELECT items FROM table WHERE color = 'blue'";
$b=mysql_query($a);
$c=mysql_num_rows($b);

for($d=0; $d<$c; $d++){$e[]=mysql_fetch_array($b); $f[]=$e[$d][0].'<br>';}
```

**Then**

```
echo array_rand($f);
```

it doesn't return **bicycle** or **phone** instead index number **0 - 1** when i refresh.

i try to put manual like `$a=[bicycle,phone]; echo array_rand($a);` its work. what's going on this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php: _“When picking only one entry, array_rand() returns __the key__ for a random entry.”_

Comment: i don't what do you means. u can try my code. by default $a=[bicycle,phone]; echo $a[0]; array_rand($a); it works. but my code stuck on get value from loop. i try access my $f manual after loop. echo $f[0] until $f[1]; it return bicycle and phone. it should be work by echo array_rand($f); what's going on?

Comment: Exactly what I quoted from the manual is ”going on”: You are picking only one random element from the array (because the second parameter to `array_rand` defaults to 1) – and _therefor_ you are getting the __key__ for the random element that was picked, not the value.

Comment: can you put code that u means? i don't know what do you means cause as i know by default i access it works. $f after loops should same as $a=[1,2]; cause i can access it $f[0] return bicycle $f[1] phone. but with array_rand it doesn't work.

Comment: What part about the fact that this function (when called like this) returns the __key__ instead of the __value__ is so hard to understand …? `$random_key = array_rand($a); echo $a[$random_key];`

Comment: i want to ask you. do you know how to use array_rand? try to make $a=[bicycle,phone]; echo array_rand($a); and refresh browser. then what different with $f? i can access $f[0] return bicycle. but why array_rand can't  use array that make from loop? just that. don't make more confuse. look my code and fix where that do wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57210/discussion-between-jarwo-bangun-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 1):

I think your loop should be like

```
for($d=0; $d<$c; $d++){
    $e[] = mysql_fetch_array($b); 
    $f[] = $e['items'].'<br>';
}
```

**EDIT:**

I think Cbroe gave the key to this question.
Full example code in mysqli, I dont do mysql, sry :)

```
//Connnection
$con = mysqli_connect( "somedbase", "dbuser", "dbpass", "dbscheme"); 

//Query string
$sql = "SELECT items FROM table WHERE color = 'blue'";

//Get results from DB
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

//Loop through result set
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    //put each row into arr
    $arr[] = $row['items'];
}

//output random array item
echo $arr[array_rand($arr)];
```

Comment: what do you means $e[0]? it doens't loop but only take 1 value. for loop $e[$d]. i try manual echo $f[0]; its work but with array_rand($f); doens't work. by default $a=[1,2]; echo $a[0]; it should be work but i dont know.

Comment: your code doesn't help what is $e['items']? it doesn't loop anything. for loop $e[$d]. u should look php manual.

Comment: You really should use the mysqli functions for new developments as mysql is to be deprecated (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: using mysql or mysqli in its situation is not relations both function it doesn't make array_rand works different.

Comment: Agree, just a solid advice :-)
Also, I think CBroe gave the key to this question. See updated answer.

Comment: ok it fixed it now. i just change echo array_rand($f); to  echo $f[array_rand($f)];. thank you for your time.

Comment: I give you a reputation but answer credit to CBroe. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL

> Order By Rand()

In you query. This will directly give you desired result.

Comment: can you put full query? but have you not think the ways i do should be work. if i try manual echo $f[0]; it works fine. but idk why it doens't work with array_rand after loop. if not loop put manual $f=[bicycle,phone]; array_rand($f); or access manual echo $f[0] its work.

Comment: `SELECT items FROM table 
WHERE color = 'blue' 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1`

Comment: thank you for your time. i just fixed it now. i give you a reputation :)

Comment: @jarwobangun mark this as answer if this helped you.